# API - Using 2 buttons to "get" and then "put" data (modified)?

Tags: swift, alamofire

My app has 2 buttons, I want 1 button to "GET" data and then another one to "PUT" the data with some modified information i have added. How would i go about this? I basically need to access the already "GET" data in the second button, but i really have to clue how to do this.

**The below code is not the full code, i removed a big part to make it easier to read. It contains a "get" function, dont know where to go from here.**

Thanks for checking it out, just looking for someone to point me in the right direction.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import QRCodeReader
import Alamofire

// MARK: - Main
struct Main: Codable {
    let objects: [Object]
}


// MARK: - Object
struct Object: Codable {
    let inventory: [Inventory]
}


// MARK: - Inventory
struct Inventory: Codable {
    let coordinates: String

}





    func test() {
        
        // MARK: - LOGIN DETAILS
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            .authorization(username: "username", password: "password"),
            .accept("application/json")]
        
        // MARK: - API REQUEST
        AF.request("URL LINK", headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in
            
            // MARK: - CHECK FOR ERRORS
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
                
                // MARK: - ERROR MESSAGE
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                { let alert = UIAlertController(title: "ERROR", message: "Something went wrong", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    
                alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
                    
                self.present(alert, animated: true)}
                return}
            
            // MARK: - PRINT RESPONSE
            if response.response != nil
            {print (response.response!) }
            
            // MARK: - PRINT DATA
            if response.data != nil
            { print(response.data!)
              let decoder = JSONDecoder()
               do
            {
                let api = try decoder.decode(Main.self, from: response.data!)
                
                let parameters = [
                        "meta": [
                            "language": "en"
                        ],
                        "request": [
                             "inventory": [
                            [
                                "id": 6534206,
                                "warehouseid": 1,
                                "instock": 3,
                                "threshold": 0,
                                "reserved": 0,
                                "coordinates": "\(api.objects[0].inventory[0].coordinates)",
                                "note": "",
                                "prodno": 25669,
                                "soldout": 0
                            ]
                        ]
                        ]
                ]
                
            }
               
               catch {
                   print("Error in JSON parsing")
               }
                
            }
            
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `let api` is a local variable inside a function. So you decode your Main object and then you throw it away.

Comment: @matt Thanks for the input, but I dont really understand what you mean, how would i be able to use the `let api` outside the function without calling it again?